# Client can't connect to flask-socketio server when rendering from a different flask route

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-socketio

I can't find the reason why my clients are not connecting to the server after being redirected to a new flask view/route/html from the "/" index.

The clients can be connected to socketio correctly through the "/" route but to no other. I haven't added any code as I think it is more of a not understanding situation, but just so you get an idea I have based my project on https://github.com/shanealynn/async_flask, just adding a new route to which when the client accesses the rendered template the connection to the socket is lost and not initiated again. I have imported the js/application.js into this new rendered html template and I think everything should be working fine, the connection just seems to not trigger.

What are the possible error sources I should be looking into?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help Qu1s. In the end I have decided to build the application as a Single Page Application (SPA) requiring only one socket, with React as the frontend generating the views dynamically and connecting to the flask application as an API.